# how to unit test a custom entity compoment system?

Tags: unit-testing, python-3.x, entity, components, pytest

I have created my own entity component system (WIP) and I wanted to add a unit test for all my systems. The problem I am facing right now is how should I use the functions inside a unit test so that they aren't dependent on other tested functions?

For instance, I have an ECSystem module which holds all basic entity/component related logic e.g adding an entity, removing an entity, etc..

```
import pytest

from EntityComponentSystem.Systems import ECSystem as ecs

class Test_ECSystem():
    @pytest.fixture(autouse = True)
    def init(self):
        ecs.initTemplates()

    def test_addEntityFromTemplate(self):
        previousLen = ecs.getEntitiesCount()
        entity = ecs.addEntityFromTemplate("player")
        assert isinstance(entity, dict)

        # Checking default entries which are needed for every entity
        assert "eid" in entity, "eid entry is missing inside the entity!"
        assert "name" in entity, "name entry is missing inside the entity!"
        assert "components" in entity, "components entry is missing inside the entity!"

        assert ecs.getEntitiesCount() == previousLen + 1, "the entity count should be incremented!"

    def test_deleteEntity(self):
        entity = ecs.addEntityFromTemplate("player")
        entityEID = entity["eid"]
        previousLen = ecs.getEntitiesCount()
        assert ecs.deleteEntity(entityEID) == True, "the entity should has been deleted successfully!"
        assert ecs.deleteEntity(entityEID) == False, "the entity should already has been deleted successfully!"
        assert ecs.getEntitiesCount() == previousLen - 1, "the entity count should be decremented!"

    def test_getEntityByName(self):
        ecs.addEntityFromTemplate("player", "playerXX")
        entity = ecs.getEntityByName("playerXX")
        assert entity["name"] == "playerXX", "the returning dict should contain the correct name!"



if __name__ == "__main__":
    pytest.main()
```

As you might see in my Test I have used functions which are also beeing tested (e.g addEntityFromTemplate()). If I would go further there would be more than that later on.

The only fix for this problem I can imagine is that I hook the entity via string into the entity list for each method test and later on empty the entity list. So at the end, every test function uses his own set of entities but this would introduce more and more code to write.

So is there any neat way of solving this type of issue?

**Edit:**

```
def addEntityFromTemplate(type, name = None):
    global __entitiesCount
    global __entities

    # create a new entity based on the entity type
    entity = dict(__entityTemplates[type])
    entity["name"] = name if name != None else type + str(__entitiesCount)
    entity["eid"] = __entitiesCount

    # add components based on reference inside entity template
    ecomponents = entity["components"]
    components = {}
    for component in ecomponents:
        components[component] = dict(__componentTemplates[component])
    entity["components"] = components

    __entities.append(entity)
    __entitiesCount += 1
    print("Added Entity from template: {0}".format(_createEntityString(entity)))

    return entity
```

So this is, for instance, the addEntityFromTemplate method. My overall ECSystem file contains only methods. And globally declared are `__entities` and `__entitiesCount`. So if I want it to test tottaly correct I have to test

- if the components are correctly assigned to the entity
- if the correct entity was returned / created (which I am currently doing with isinstace(..., dict)
- if the entity count increased

But I am totally lost on doing it correct.

Comment: The test functions (each representing a test case) are independent anyway (unless you use some shared global variable or introduce a dependency). In your example above, you may: 1.) Remove the class (py.test doesn't need the class). 2.) Create unit-test cases each having a single assert each (smaller the unit-tests, better they are - test one thing at a time.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, I now classes are optional ;) ... But how would I then test for example the addEntityFromTemplate function correctly?. (I will edit my question adding the addEntityFromTemplate function.)

Comment: from EntityComponentSystem.Systems.ECSystem import addEntityFromTemplate

Comment: Also, I'd recommend avoiding globals.